# C: Remove function cannot remove txt file

Tags: c

I used the "remove" function in my program but when I execute it, it doesn't delete the file passed to the `remove` function. The files are all in the same folder.

this is the syntax:

```
remove("myfile.txt");
```

Comment: What's your current-working-directory at the moment you execute your program?  Since you gave a relative path, your program will try to find a file called `myfile.txt` relative to your cwd, specifically.

Comment: Check the return value, and then check `errno`.

Comment: eg: `if( remove(path) ){ perror(path); ... `

Comment: I execute the program from the inside of the directory with the main.c and the txt file.
This is the folder structure: Folder:
                                                     -  executable.exe
                                                     -  main.c
                                                     -  myfile.txt

Comment: Ok, i will try to check the return value

Comment: @WilliamPursell database.txt: Permission denied

Comment: So you don't have write permission on the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothesis #1: You are programming on Windows and the file is readonly.

Hypothesis #2: You are programming on Windows and are in a directory under Program Files (x86) and got bit by UAC nonsense. Don't put your files under Program Files (x86).